# The right datastructure for selecting objects

Tags: java, performance, data-structures

I'm new to Java and as a learning project, I would like to program a little vocabulary application, so that the user can test himself but also search for entries. However, I struggle to find the right datastructure for this and even after spending the last few days googling for it, I'm still at a loss.

Here is what I have in mind for my vocabulary object:

```
import java.io.*;

class Vocab implements Serializable {
String lang1;
String lang2;
int rightAnswersInARow;  // to influence what to ask during testing
int numberOfTimesSearched;  // to influence search suggestions

    // ... plus the appropriate setter and getter methods.
}
```

1. Now for the testing, at first glance an `ArrayList` seems to be the most appropriate (choosing a random number and then selecting that object to test). But what if I would also like to factor in the `rightAnswersInARow` and ask vocabularies with a low number more often? My approach would be count the number of objects for each value, give each value an interval (e.g. the interval for `rightAnswersInARow = 0` would be inflated by the factor 3) and then randomly select from there.
   But even if I go through the `ArrayList` each time, get the `rightAnswersInARow` and determine the intervals...how would I then map the calculated number to the right index since the elements are not sorted? So would a `TreeSet` be more appropriate?
2. To search for entries in both languages and maybe even adding a dropdown-list with suggested words (like in Google's search) would require that I find the strings quickly (`HashMap`?). Or maybe go through 2+ (one for each language) `TreeSet`s to reach the first element that starts with those letters, then selecting the next few elements from there? But that would mean the search would always suggest the same words, ignoring which words were searched for the most.

What would you suggest? Have a `HashMap` with each value pair and manually implement something like a relational database?

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Trie should be your friend as the data structure for storing dictionary words. See this https://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/courses/cps108/fall96/joggle/trie/Trie.java

Comment: @saury interesting. at first i thought you had a typo but this looks actually very interesting ;)

Comment: Thank you guys for your reply! If I understand correctly, Tries would be the way to go implement the search functionality. But selecting a random element with a certain probability based on the object's properties and also sorting by other properties would still require another datastructure, correct?